# Send json array and passing json array in spring mvc controller

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying pass Json data such bellow

```
for (var t = 0; t < files.length; t ++ ){
    contents.push({"name":files[t].name,"selected":true,"url":files[t].url});               
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/candidate/onboarding/multidownload",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody RequestTTT downloadCandidateDoc(HttpServletResponse res,@RequestBody List<DownloadItem> files) {
    requestttt.setFiles(files);
    return requestttt;  
}
```

Class RequestTTT

```
class RequestTTT {
    Long candidateId;
    List<DownloadItem> files;
}
```

Class DownloadItem

```
public class DownloadItem {
    private String name;
    private boolean selected;
}
```

Result i have is :

> 400 Bad request with function

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "${contextPath}/ajax/candidate/onboarding/multidownload",
  data : JSON.stringify(data),
  dataType: 'json',
  headers : {
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  },
  cache: false,
  timeout: 100000,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
  },
  error: function (e) {
    console.log("ERROR : ", e);
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you please post  request Json sample?

Comment: [{"name":"logo.png","selected":true,"url":"http://192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/120170623163651logo.png"},{"name":"Chrysanthemum.jpg","selected":true,"url":"http://192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/120170630103251Chrysanthemum.jpg"},{"name":"hgignore_global.txt","selected":true,"url":"http://192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/120181115023903hgignore_global.txt"},{"name":"logo.png","selected":true,"url":"http://192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/120170623163651logo.png"}]

Comment: @Md.SajedulKarim What is the response body that you get along with the 400? Do you see any error message in the logs of your spring app?

Comment: @Huynh.tdt , Please check my answer. I added working code. I checked it in Postman. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response.

**Request List item Class**:

```
public class DownloadItem {

    private String name;
    private String selected;
    private String url;

    /*{
        "name": "logo.png",
            "selected": true,
            "url": "192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/120170623163651logo.png"
    }*/


    // Getter
    // Setter
}
```

**Response Class**:

```
import java.util.List;


public class Response {
    private Long candidateId;
    private List<DownloadItem> files;


    // Getter
    // Setter
}
```

**Your controller code will be bellow**:

```
@PostMapping("ajax/candidate/onboarding/multidownload")
public ResponseEntity<Response> downloadCandidateDoc(@RequestBody List<DownloadItem> request) {

    Response response=new Response();
    response.setCandidateId(11L);
    response.setFiles(request);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

**Here is imports**:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
```

**Edit**:

I checked this in **postman**. Here is the sample input output.
**http://IP:PORT/YOUR_CONTEXT_PATH/ajax/candidate/onboarding/multidownload**

**Request Json**

```
[
  {
    "name": "logo.png",
    "selected": true,
    "url": "192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/120170623163651logo.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "Chrysanthemum.jpg",
    "selected": true,
    "url": "192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/…"
  }
]
```

**Response**:

```
{
    "candidateId": 11,
    "files": [
        {
            "name": "logo.png",
            "selected": "true",
            "url": "192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/120170623163651logo.png"
        },
        {
            "name": "Chrysanthemum.jpg",
            "selected": "true",
            "url": "192.168.84.30/static/candidate/india/1/…"
        }
    ]
}
```